# Is there a way to store intermediate values when using solve_ivp?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I'm working on a system of differential equation that I solve with scipy.integrate.solve_ivp. For each variation term of this system I combine different intermediate variables. I'm looking for a way to store those intermediate variables and not only the resulting variables.

I've thinking to use a list or some other kind of iterable to store the intermediate values directly in the func passed to solve_ivp but it doesn't seem to be the best approach and doesn't allow me to use the interpolants, when using a dense_output.
I could also recompute those intermediate variables by using the results of solve_ivp, but as the computation are somehow complicated it should be way easier to store directly the values and only compute them only once.

My func function looks like that :

```py
def dY(t, Y):
    C1, C2 = Y

    dC1 = A(C1, C2) + B(C1, C2)
    dC2 = C(C1, C2) + B(C1, C2)

    return [dC1, dC2]
```

I would like to store the values of A, B, C and D at each step, as are the values of C1 and C2 (for those to whom it speaks, it's a chemical engineering problem and A, B, C and D are different sink and source terms)

Thanks for any helps !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the values of the solutions and call the functions after the fact.  Do not use intermediate values that get stored inside the `dY` function.  Stiff ODE integrators will call the function multiple times during a time step, you will end up with meaningless data getting stored.  Nonstiff ODE integrators *might* also attempt multiple time steps within one try which will have the same problem.

Here is an example of how to reconstruct A and B after the fact:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tspan = (0, 10)
y0 = [1, 2]

def A(C1, C2):
    return 2*C1 + 3*C2 - C1**2
def B(C1, C2):
    return 1*C1 + 4*C2
def C(C1, C2):
    return 1*C1 + 3*C2 - C2**2
def D(C1, C2):
    return 2*C1 + 5*C2
def dY(t, Y):
    C1, C2 = Y

    dC1 = A(C1, C2) + B(C1, C2)
    dC2 = C(C1, C2) + B(C1, C2)

    return [dC1, dC2]
sol = solve_ivp(dY, tspan, y0)

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0], label='C1')
ax.plot(sol.t, sol.y[1], label='C2')
ax.legend()
fig2,ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.plot(sol.t, A(sol.y[0], sol.y[1]), label='A')
ax2.plot(sol.t, B(sol.y[0], sol.y[1]), label='B')
ax2.legend()
```

Comment: I assumed it's the better way to do it. I then refactored my code to make it easier to reconstruct A and B after the resolution.