# extracting, printing and plotting intermediary values from solve_ivp

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am using solve_ivp to solve a series of integrated differential equations. The below code is a simplified representation of a much larger code. I would like to be able to extract and plot/print 'over time', the evolving values of intermediary values, (eg) A_value vs t.

I have tried adding a counter, and adding the current value of 'A_value' to a list every iteration through A(t, pools), and this does work - but the problem is in the full version of this model, this becomes excessively large - I run into storage space/size issues (200+ intermediary calculations I would like to follow, my storage array size is upwards of a million per variable).  I'm trying to find out if there is a way to do this more efficiently. I would like something that will allow the final plot A_value vs t.

I also tried this solution: [Is there a way to store intermediate values when using solve_ivp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57823091/is-there-a-way-to-store-intermediate-values-when-using-solve-ivp) , but I really need all of the intermediary variables within one method (due to size), and I can't quite recreate their plotting results (does it work?).

(Other notes: I know that 'time' doesn't do anything in my A(t, pools) method, I was just re-creating the structure of the bigger model, where t is a required variable in that method. I am sure I am also using 'global' incorrectly, but was just trying anything...)

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated! How can I save the data and plot A_value vs t, without using a counter. I'm still a python 'newbie', and trying to learn by doing. Thanks in advance

"""

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tspan = (0, 10)     #set the start and stop time
pools0 = [1, 2]         #set the initial values

def A(t, pools):

    global A_value
    global B_value
    global C_value
    global D_value
    global time

    time = t
    if (time ==0):
        cows = 1.0

    C1, C2 = pools      #the pools get saved in here

    A_value = 2*C1 + 3*C2 - C1**2
    B_value = 1*C1 + 4*C2
    C_value = 1*C1 + 3*C2 - C2**2
    D_value = 2*C1 + 5*C2

    print(time, A_value, B_value, C_value, D_value)     # essentially, how this prints, I want to be able to save/store this data

    return [time, A_value, B_value, C_value, D_value]

time, A_value, B_value, C_value, D_value = A(t, pools)

def model_integ(t, pools):

    global A_value
    global B_value
    global C_value
    global D_value
    global time

    time, A_value, B_value, C_value, D_value = A(t, pools)

    dC1 = A_value + B_value
    dC2 = C_value + D_value

    return [dC1, dC2]       # return the differential

pools = solve_ivp(model_integ, tspan, pools0)

#print(A(pools.y[0], pools.y[1]) )

C1, C2 = pools.y
t = pools.t

print(t, C1, C2)      # this works fine, pulling the t, C1, C2 values from model_integ() for printing
print(time, A_value, B_value, C_value, D_value)     # this only prints out their FINAL values


# C1 pool vs t, storage variables
#---------------------------------------------------------------
plt.scatter(t,C1)
plt.xlabel("t, d")      # adding labels and title on the plot
plt.ylabel("C1 pools")    # adding labels and title on the plot
#plt.ylim(0.0,2500)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.title("C1/C2 change with time")   # adding labels and title on the plot
plt.tight_layout()      # this takes care of labels overflowing the plot. It's good to use it all the time.
plot_file = "cute_little_plot.png"  # output file to save plot
plt.savefig(plot_file)  # output file to save plot
plt.show()
plt.close()

# A_value vs t, storage variables
#---------------------------------------------------------------
plt.scatter(t,A_value)
plt.xlabel("t, d")      # adding labels and title on the plot
plt.ylabel("A_value")    # adding labels and title on the plot
#plt.ylim(0.0,2500)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.title("A_value change with time")   # adding labels and title on the plot
plt.tight_layout()      # this takes care of labels overflowing the plot. It's good to use it all the time.
plot_file = "Avalue_plot.png"  # output file to save plot
plt.savefig(plot_file)  # output file to save plot
plt.show()
plt.close()
"""
```

Comment: You would be better served if you fashion your own time loop using the RK45 stepper class. Then you get fine control of what and when to print, without hacking the ODE function.

Comment: Hi Lutz, thank you so much for your reply. I am still new to python - I've just been searching for an example of how this would be applied - this would be using this approach? http://hplgit.github.io/primer.html/doc/pub/ode2/._ode2-readable003.html

Comment: While that is a nice systematic way to implement the standard Runge-Kutta methods, what I meant was something similar to the second half of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64225219/3088138